# How to get parameters in cloudformation template to launch using Amazon Go SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, parameters, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk

I am having trouble writing a script in Golang to launch a cloudformation template that has several parameters.  I am new to both sdk and golang, so I am running into several syntax errors.

I have tried running the code in VS studio.

```
func runCFTscript(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String("us-west-1")},
    )

    // Create Cloudformation service client
    svc := cloudformation.New(sess)

    // Specify the details of the instance that you want to create.
    runResult, err := svc.CreateStack(&cloudformation.CreateStackInput{


        Parameters: []cloudformation.Parameter{
            {
                ParameterKey:   aws.String("Keyname"),
                ParameterValue: aws.String("testXXX"),
                ParameterKey:   aws.String("InstanceType"),
                ParameterValue: aws.String("t2.micro"),
                ParameterKey:   aws.String("SSHLocation"),
                ParameterValue: aws.String("0.0.0.0/0"),
            },
        },
        StackName:   aws.String("test"),
        TemplateURL: aws.String("https://test.com"),
    })
}
```

Error code:

```
./cloudformation.go:27:3: cannot use []cloudformation.Parameter literal (type []cloudformation.Parameter) as type []*cloudformation.Parameter in field value
./cloudformation.go:31:5: duplicate field name in struct literal: ParameterKey
./cloudformation.go:32:5: duplicate field name in struct literal: ParameterValue
./cloudformation.go:33:5: duplicate field name in struct literal: ParameterKey
./cloudformation.go:34:5: duplicate field name in struct literal: ParameterValue
./main.go:55:6: main redeclared in this block
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to provide a `[]Parameter` containing a single `Parameter` object with duplicate fields (as the error says) where you need a. You need to pass a `[]*Parameter` containing a *pointer* for each parameter you want to pass, all in the slice:

```
    Parameters: []*cloudformation.Parameter{
        &cloudformation.Parameter{
            ParameterKey:   aws.String("Keyname"),
            ParameterValue: aws.String("testXXX"),
        },
        &cloudformation.Parameter{
            ParameterKey:   aws.String("InstanceType"),
            ParameterValue: aws.String("t2.micro"),
        },
        &cloudformation.Parameter{
            ParameterKey:   aws.String("SSHLocation"),
            ParameterValue: aws.String("0.0.0.0/0"),
        },
    },
```

(It looks like you also have `main` declared twice in another file, but that source isn't shown and the error is unrelated.)

Comment: Thank you Adrian!

Comment: However, I am running into a problem in cloudformation as it is not executing my cloudformation function.  So I have an api, when I trigger the GET endpoint it will execute the create cloudformation template.  However, at the moment, it is doing nothing.  I am not sure how to troubleshoot the problem.  If anyone can give any advice, that would be great

Comment: We'd need more information than that. You can open a new question if you're having other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I used [aws go sdk v2](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudformation) to get it working.

Add "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/cloudformation" in the import section and then,

Try this out:-

```
Parameters: []types.Parameter{
                {
                    ParameterKey:   aws.String("Keyname"),
                    ParameterValue: aws.String("testXXX"),
                },
                {
                    ParameterKey:   aws.String("InstanceType"),
                    ParameterValue: aws.String("t2.micro"),
                },
                {
                    ParameterKey:   aws.String("SSHLocation"),
                    ParameterValue: aws.String("0.0.0.0/0"),
                },
            },
```